# Configuring channelized E1

Tags: routing

Can someone let me know if the following configuring is correct on our E1 controller and serial interface for bandwidth of 1984.

We're currently upgrading our bandwidth from 512 to 1984, but I'm not sure if the following configuration will work for bandwidth of 1984

```
controller E1 0/0/0
 channel-group 0 timeslots 1-31
!         

!
interface Serial0/0/0:0
 description - TBA
 bandwidth 1984
 no ip address
 encapsulation frame-relay
 ip route-cache flow
 frame-relay lmi-type ansi
end
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone let me know if the following configuring is correct on our
>   E1 controller and serial interface for bandwidth of 1984.

Yes, it's the correct config for using all timeslots of a framed controller.

This a configuration taken from an actual device (yes, the bandwidth is incorrect):

```
controller E1 3/0/4
 channel-group 0 timeslots 1-31

interface Serial3/0/4:0
 bandwidth 2048
 ip address S.N.I.P 255.255.255.252
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 encapsulation ppp
 no snmp trap link-status
 no fair-queue
 no cdp enable
end
```